# Redirect to HTTPS in Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I have a blazor app.
I hosted it on server and have access with https.
But when i do redirect (in one controller), happens exception.

Startap.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseResponseCompression();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
        });

        app.Map("/schedule", subdirApp =>
        {
            subdirApp.UseBlazor<Client.Startup>();
        });
    }
```

And method in controller

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("***")]
public IActionResult Return()
{
   FileStream fs = new FileStream(_filePath, FileMode.Open);
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
   List<ScheduleEntity> _list = (List<ScheduleEntity>)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
   foreach (var x in _list)
       Schedules.Add(x);
   fs.Close();
   return Redirect("~//schedule");
}
```

Exception

[image]

Please, help me

Answer (score 0):

These API responses can be a bit misleading. Without seeing the rest of your code around the configuration of endpoints, I suspect this might be a CORS issue with the API.

Try adding the following code to the `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)` method in your API's `Startup.cs` class:

```
        app.UseCors(opts => opts
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials()
        );
```

The fetch response may be due to the request preflight being rejected.

Having said that, the first exception message is saying you're trying to load insecure content, so I'd also check your Blazor front-end app's configuration to see what the API client is requesting and ensure the API endpoint certificate is valid?